# Can't work extended display

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have been working with 2 screens for a while (Windows 8), as an extended desktop. Everything has been working fine, moving a window or the curser from one screen to the other is no problem.

Today I had to do a reboot and after the reboot both screens are active, but the second screen only shows the taskbar and a blank screen.  I can't move the cursor to it - it just bumps up against the edge of the first display and won't move over.  Likewise, if I slide a window across it doesn't go onto the second display.

How to I get it back to normal use?

Comment: When you say you "had" to reboot is this because of updates? If so, you could try uninstalling these updates and see if it  was causing the issue or try safe mode to make sure it's not a driver issue.

Comment: Unless the reason you had to update was because it told you it was having a video adapter issue. ;)  Anyhow, we need more info.  Have you tried just using the usual Windows display settings to confirm the orientation, and configure them how you'd like?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer myself, which I will post for anyone with the same problem.  Turns out after the reboot the system didn't recognize the physical positions of the monitors.  To fix, which was by accident testing things out, I did the following:

Right click a blank area on the desktop and select Screen Resolution.  A picture of the two displays comes up.

Click Identify.  Large numerals appear on the monitors and that's when I realised they were switched back to front - the monitor that is actually on the right appeared on the left in this layout.

Drag the picture of the monitor that's in the wrong location into the right location and click Apply.

Problem solved.

Comment: Don't forget to "answer" your own question's answer... additionally, put up some screenshots of the solution to give people an idea what to look for :)